# Why is the namespace pattern for CustomData a full http address and index suffix

Tags: xml-namespaces, sapui5

In UI5, customdata is used to contain additional parameters that are passed to event handlers in the eventControl.data() object. This is akin to jquery data functionality.

In an XML view definition for UI5 we have to define namespaces. In all the documentation and examples I have stumbled across on the web so far, the namespace for customdata has a pattern that references a specific http address AND a specific index number suffix, whereas the pattern for all others I have met thus far has been not included either.

See example below where customdata is the last entry in the list.

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sapui5.muSample.controller.Master"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"     
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:c="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
    >
```

If I want to run OpenUI5 entirely from my servers hard drive thus without referring to any external sources, how can I alter the reference to customdata? Or am I misunderstanding and is the use of the http prefix NOT going to invoke communication across the web to the given address? If so I am even more confused.

I would like to understand the reason for the full http reference and index suffix AND know how to replace it with an entirely local reference. I tried to make a local reference but without success and I suspect there is more going on here than I grok.

EDIT: I have learned from the Internet and proven with Fiddler that the web address used in the namespace is not for use in communications. So I guess the clue might be the /1 suffix. Still confused though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f0c3ee6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) the difference between this namespace and the other namespaces is intentional. Whatever that means. In general the URI is used to define unique namespace names and is not used by the [parser](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_namespaces.asp).

Comment: Thanks that pretty much matches to what I discovered in the code. The docs mention of the reason for the difference being intentional is finite if not expansive. I notice that you are a frequent UI5 responder - can I ask if you are aware of any other examples of the more formal namespace format? PS Upvoted for your efforts.

Comment: Accepting @matbtt's answer but see mine for details of the http and /1.

Comment: Thanks for upvote. Actually I'm not aware of other examples. But this does not mean that they do not exist. Although I'm using UI5 on a daily basis I definetly do not have an overview about all its aspects.

Answer (score 2):

Answering for myself in case it helps someone else and to solicit corrections from community if needed.

I searched the debug source of UI5 for the string `"http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"` and found a match in XMLTemplateProcessor-dbg.js wherein there is an if statement seeking this precise string.

My conclusions are:

1. This is nothing more than a namespace that does not match the general pattern in UI5 namespacing that I have experienced to date. Possibly a 'coded-by-a-separate-team' issue or some similar human cause.
2. The namespace text is arbitrary and has no meaning other than being a match to that needed in the UI5 code.
3. In a general namespace context, the /1 suffix would be an indication of version number of the namespace - a way of versioning the namespace over time. But this has no impact in this usage in UI5.
4. The http prefix, in the UI5 context, has no implication of communication and does not make the client reach out to the specified web address (proven by Fiddler observations).

End.